# Is DynamoDB Version Agnostic

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-local

I am new to DynamoDB and trying to learn, while going through the docs I got a doubt whether DynamoDB is version agnostic or not also I want to know wether it is backwards compatible or not?
In addition I also want to know how to download local DynamoDB of different versions if possible and how can I change the version of DynamoDB in the webservice of aws ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dynamoDB` is a cloud hosted datastore. It it not a piece of software that you  can download or install. As far as I know, there is no version, and you can't/don't have to select any version anywhere.

At most you can use some docker containers that *mimics* the behavior of dynamoDB to some extend. They are useful for testing and dev purposes, but keep in mind they are just mocks.

Comment: First they also provide a local setup for downloading and free use
Second in the docs there is some detailing about 1.x and 2.x versions so versions are there

Comment: There are versions of the SDK, DynamoDB.local, and in specific features, e.g. global tables. So, @aherve is correct.